# How to use point shapes other than spheres in rgl?

Tags: r, 3d, shapes, rgl

I'm trying to illustrate the idea of projections using points on a cube, shown with `rgl` and what that
looks like in various 2D projections.

My goal is to use different colors and shapes to distinguish the points, both in 2D plots and 3D,
but I can't figure out how to plot the points in `rgl` using other than  spheres.

My current figure looks like this:

[image]

I generate the points on a 10^3 cube and two projections as:

```
vals <- c(0, 10)
X <- expand.grid(x1 = vals, x2=vals, x3=vals) |> as.matrix()

# project on just x1, x2 plane
P1 <- rbind(diag(2), c(0,0))
Y1 <- X %*% P1
# oblique projection
P2 <- matrix(c(0.71, 0.71, 0, -0.42, .42, 0.84), ncol=2)
Y2 <- X %*% P2
```

The 2D plots in (b) and (c) use 4 different colors and 4 `pch` shapes (square, circle, triangle, diamond)

```
pch <- rep(15:18, 2)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "darkgreen", "brown")
col <- rep(colors, each = 2)

plot(Y1, cex = 3, 
     pch = pch, col = col,
     xlab = "Y[,1]", ylab = "Y[,2]",
     xlim = c(-1, 11), ylim = c(-1, 11))

plot(Y2, cex = 3, 
     pch = pch, col = col,
     xlab = "Y[,1]", ylab = "Y[,2]",
     xlim = c(-1, 15), ylim = c(-5, 14)
     )
```

Here's what I tried using `rgl`. The colors are correct, but obviously, `pch` has no effect using `type = "s"`.
What I'd like are the shapes: cube, sphere, pyramid, diamond (or anything else)

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(X, type = "s", size = 2,  pch = pch, col = col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type = "n"` to set up the plotting region, then `pch3d()` to plot symbols at the points.  For example,

```r
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(X, type = "n")
pch3d(X, pch = pch, col = col)
```

[image]

If you want to use 3d shapes, it's a bit harder.  The `sprites3d()` function can do it, but it plots the same shape at each location, so you'll need to call it several times to plot different shapes.  The example below creates 3 shapes, and then plots each of them a few times:

```r
open3d()
plot3d(X, type = "n")
shapes <- c(shade3d(cube3d(), col = "red"),
            shade3d(tetrahedron3d(), col = "blue"),
            shade3d(octahedron3d(), col = "darkgreen"),
            shade3d(sphere3d(), col = "brown")
# sprites3d can only plot the same shapes at each location,
# so we'll call it 3 times
indx <- 1:8
for (i in 1:3) {
  j <- indx[indx %% 3 == i %% 3]
  sprites3d(X[j,,drop=FALSE], shape = shapes[i])
}
```

[image]

EDITED TO ADD:

Finally, if you're willing and able to use the development version of `rgl`, `sprites3d()` now handles cases like yours more easily.  For `rgl` version 1.2.13 or higher, the code above could be written as

```r
# spheres3d() doesn't work well as a sprite, so make a sphere mesh:

sphere3d <- addNormals(subdivision3d(icosahedron3d(), 2))

open3d()
plot3d(X, type = "n")
shapes <- list(shade3d(cube3d(), col = "red"),
            shade3d(tetrahedron3d(), col = "blue"),
            shade3d(octahedron3d(), col = "darkgreen"),
            shade3d(sphere3d, col = "brown"))

shapes <- rep(shapes, each = 2)

sprites3d(X, shape = shapes)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know of `pch3d()`.  It would be nice to be able to use 3D solid shapes other than spheres, but this works well enough for my example

Comment: You can use solid shapes if you want --- see `sprites3d()`.

Comment: This would be a nice documentation example in `rgl`. For my purpose, it would be perfect if I could also use a sphere, or have a 4th shape in 3d I could match to what I do in the 2d plots.